# Improving speed of data clean process in vba

Tags: performance, vba, excel

My code does exactly what I want it to. However, being relatively new to VBA, I feel it could be a lot more efficient - namely I think I have overused loops and worksheet functions which are slowing it down. At the moment it takes around 3 minutes for ~15k rows of data.

Currently it's more of a combination of separate steps joined together so it doesn't flow nicely, rather for each steps it iterates through every row which, while it gets the job done, is frustratingly inefficient.

At the moment I am trying to remove the loops perhaps using Range objects instead, but I would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

```
Sub RunDataClean_Click()
With Sheets("Data")
'ensures code only loops through rows with data and not full worksheet
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    endrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A4"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
Else
    endrow = 4
End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long

'Checks another sheet to see if we have the cleaned customer name on file
For i = 5 To endrow

'does a vlookup in CDM file
Acc = Application.Cells(i, 5)
Cname = Application.Cells(i, 4)

Acname = Application.VLookup(Acc, Sheet3.Range("D2:F315104"), 3, False)
If IsError(Acname) Then
    Cells(i, 32).Value = ""
Else
    Cells(i, 32).Value = Acname
End If

Map = Application.VLookup(Acc, Sheet3.Range("C2:F315104"), 4, False)
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 32)) Then
    If IsError(Map) Then
        Cells(i, 32).Value = ""
    Else
        Cells(i, 32).Value = Map
    End If
End If

FXid = Application.VLookup(Acc, Sheet3.Range("B2:F315104"), 5, False)
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 32)) Then
    If IsError(FXid) Then
        Cells(i, 32).Value = ""
    Else
        Cells(i, 32).Value = FXid
    End If
End If

FXP = Application.VLookup(Cname, Sheet3.Range("A2:F315104"), 6, False)
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 32)) Then
    If IsError(FXP) Then
        Cells(i, 32).Value = ""
    Else
        Cells(i, 32).Value = FXP
    End If
End If

LkpName = Application.VLookup(Cname, Sheet3.Range("F2:F315104"), 1, False)
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 32)) Then
    If IsError(LkpName) Then
        Cells(i, 32).Value = ""
    Else
        Cells(i, 32).Value = LkpName
    End If
End If

If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 32)) Then
    Cells(i, 32).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
End If

Next i
For i = 5 To endrow

Cells(i, 28).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & Cells(i, 5).Value
Length = Len(Cells(i, 28))
Cells(i, 29).Value = Length
Cells(i, 31).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value

'does a vlookup in CDM file (CDM)
Acc = Application.Cells(i, 28)
BP = Application.VLookup(Acc, Sheet3.Range("E2:G315104"), 3, False)
If IsError(BP) Then
    Cells(i, 30).Value = ""
Else
    Cells(i, 30).Value = BP
End If

'assigns B or P based on payment details (Business_Personal)
If Cells(i, 12).Value = "N" Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf Cells(i, 30).Value = "Business" Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf Cells(i, 30).Value = "Personal" Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "P"
ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value = "Y" Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "P"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "LTD") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "LIMITED") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "MANAGE") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "BUSINESS") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "CONSULT") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "INTERNATIONAL") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "T/A") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "TECH") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "CLUB") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "OIL") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "SERVICE") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "SOLICITOR") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, 32), "CORP") <> 0 Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "B"
ElseIf Left(Cells(i, 5).Value, 3) = "999" Then
    Cells(i, 24).Value = "P"
End If
Next i

'Week_Of_Year
For i = 5 To endrow
WeekNo = Application.Cells(i, 1)
WeekNumba = Application.WeekNum(WeekNo)
Cells(i, 21).Value = WeekNumba
Next i

'Deal_Channel concatenation
For i = 5 To endrow
Cells(i, 22).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value & Cells(i, 13).Value & Cells(i, 17).Value
Next i

'Deal_Source_System
For i = 5 To endrow
DealSS = Application.Cells(i, 22)

Deal_Source = Application.VLookup(DealSS, Sheet4.Range("F2:H354"), 3, False)
If IsError(Deal_Source) Then
    Cells(i, 23).Value = "#N/A"
Else
    Cells(i, 23).Value = Deal_Source
End If
Next i

'Reporting_Quarter (only worked for type double)
'does a lookup in calendar tab to return reporting quarter - could move this to Access
For i = 5 To endrow
qdate = Cells(i, 1)
qlkp = Application.VLookup(CDbl(qdate), Sheet5.Range("A1:C500"), 3, False)
Cells(i, 26).Value = qlkp
Next i

'copies any #N/A deal channel to lookup tables and then sets deal source to map
lastrow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheet1.Range("W5:W" & endrow)
Set DS = .Find(What:="#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not DS Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = DS.Address
    Do
        DS.Offset(, -1).Copy
        Sheet3.Range("F" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        DS.Value = "Map"
        Set DS = .FindNext(DS)
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    Loop While Not DS Is Nothing
End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This procedure looks like a `Click` event handler for some button. What kind of module is it written in? Whether it's a worksheet module or a standard module will make a significant difference in how reliable this code is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it's in a form control command button. This was easiest so whoever I pass this process onto just has to click a button but I could use another type if that would help

Comment: One more question: a lot of this code could very well be substituted for Excel functions that, I'm pretty sure, would calculate much faster than 3 minutes. There *are* ways to make the code run faster, but I can't shake the feeling that most of it should be replaced with worksheet functions. Is there a specific reason not to?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the main reason was to get rid of the manual side of the process - dragging formulas etc. Nobody wants to spend time on it (needs to be done weekly) so the idea was that they could click a button and then forget about it

Answer (score 2):

Code that's hard to read, is code that's hard to modify *without breaking*. Consistent indentation helps with that:

> ```
> For i = 5 To endrow
> qdate = Cells(i, 1)
> qlkp = Application.VLookup(CDbl(qdate), Sheet5.Range("A1:C500"), 3, False)
> Cells(i, 26).Value = qlkp
> Next i
> ```

```
For i = 5 To endrow
    qdate = Cells(i, 1)
    qlkp = Application.VLookup(CDbl(qdate), Sheet5.Range("A1:C500"), 3, False)
    Cells(i, 26).Value = qlkp
Next i
```

That's already better!

The first thing I would do would be to indent the entire project in a single click with [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), and then review the inspection results:

[image: Rubberduck inspection results]

Undeclared variables are a huge red flag: `Option Explicit` isn't specified and VBA will happily compile any typos and carry on running the code in an erroneous logical state, by declaring the new identifier on-the-spot as an implicit `Variant`. Using disemvoweled, abbreviated, and otherwise unpronounceable names makes it even easier for this to happen, and harder for the bugs it introduces to be found.

Since this code is in the code-behind of a `UserForm`, there are *a lot* of implicit `ActiveSheet` references, and this is making the code extremely frail, prone to blow up with error 1004, or to work off the wrong sheet (although, not `Select`ing and `Activate`ing any sheets and toggling `ScreenUpdating` off *does* minimize the odds of that happening, albeit indirectly).

There's a `Range.Find` call at the top of the procedure that assumes there is data on the `Sheets("Data")` worksheet. In the event where that sheet would be empty, the chained `.Row` member call would raise error 91.

> ```
> Acc = Application.Cells(i, 5)
> Cname = Application.Cells(i, 4)
> ```

These instructions are invoking worksheet members off `Application`: it's equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Cells`, or simply `Cells`. Just reading the code isn't sufficient to understand what sheet that is expected to be active, and thus all these unqualified `Cells` calls are very ambiguous, at least for a reader that doesn't know what they're looking at.

Barring a few false positives, everything Rubberduck picks up is essentially a low-hanging fruit that should be addressed before deving into the more substantial stuff:

- Implicit `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` references, should be qualified with a specific `Worksheet` or `Workbook` object, or explicitly reference `ActiveSheet`/`ActiveWorkbook`, to clarify the intent of the code. I believe the intent is not to work off whatever workbook/sheet is currently active though.
- Avoid Systems Hungarian Notation prefixing. It's harmful, and brings no value.
- Don't make event handler procedures `Public`, implicitly or not. Event handlers are `Private` by default, and they should remain that way: they are meant to be invoked by VBA, not user code.
- Use string-typed functions where possible, e.g. `Left` takes and returns a `Variant`, but `Left$` takes and returns an actual `String`: that's a rather insignificant (to an extent) point performance-wise, but using explicit types should be preferred over `Variant` (and the slight run-time overhead using `Variant` incurs).

---

Since a `UserForm` is involved, I encourage you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291028/1188513) and the article it links to (I wrote both). The crux being, the last thing you want is to have a form that manipulates a worksheet directly, inside some button's `Click` handler. A first step towards a thorough refactoring would to turn the click handler into something like this:

```
Private Sub RunDataClean_Click()
    Macros.RunDataClean
End Sub
```

...and then move the entire body of the procedure into a `Public Sub RunDataClean` procedure in some `Macros` module, but that's just a first step.

---

Performance-wise, it's hard to justify all that VBA code to do work that looks very much like it could be done using standard worksheet formulas.

But one thing strikes me:

> ```
> For i = 5 To endrow
> ```

This line appears 6 times in the procedure, so the macro is iterating every single one of these 15K rows, ...6 times. Remove all but the first `For i = 5 To endrow` and all but the last `Next i`, and you will likely instantly slash 83% of the work being done.

Comment: Thanks so much Mathieu I really appreciate the help! I'll get working on tidying it up like you have suggested